# why getBoundingClientRect would be undefined on a dom element?

Tags: javascript, firefox, dom, getboundingclientrect

This issue seem to occur only on Firefox:

I've got  an error saying "getBoundingClientRect is not a function" on a valid dom element included in the page:

```
var flashElement = document.getElementById("flash_2ffe3a7c");
```

result:

```
<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" id="flash_2ffe3a7c" name="flash_2ffe3a7c" data="http://www.url.com/myfile.swf" wmode="transparent" style="top: 0px; left: 0px; z-index: 4102; position: absolute; width: 399px; height: 6px;" width="399" height="6">
```

**flashElement.nodeType**  is 1

**flashElement.nodeName**  is OBJECT

but

**flashElement.getBoundingClientRect** is undefined.

whereas

**flashElement.getClientRects** is a function.

Is there a known reason why **getBoundingClientRect** is undefined?